# keepalived and two active servers

Tags: linux, load-balancing

I'm trying to configure two active load balancer servers with **keepalived**.

It differs a little from standard configuration, where we have two servers and one virtual IP.

All I want is when **loadbalancer_1** goes down, then **loadbalancer_2** takes his IP-address, and vice versa.

**loadbalancer_1** IP-address: xx.237.193.132/27
**loadbalancer_2** IP-address: xx.237.193.134/27

When I start **loadbalancer_1** at first time, it takes also the **loadbalancer_2** IP-address, because at that particular moment **keepalived** isn't started yet on **loadbalancer_2**.
But when I'm starting **loadbalancer_2** there are still his IP-address on **loadbalancer_1**. So, **loadbalancer_1**. Is a master for two IP-addresses.

The same occurs, when I start **loadbalancer_2** first, so those server that was started earlier will be a master for two IP-addresses.

Log on **loadbalancer_1**:

```
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_healthcheckers[9750]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_healthcheckers[9750]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_healthcheckers[9750]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: Configuration is using : 71869 Bytes
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Entering BACKUP STATE
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_healthcheckers[9750]: Configuration is using : 12587 Bytes
Jul 19 19:18:00 001 Keepalived_healthcheckers[9750]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Jul 19 19:18:01 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Jul 19 19:18:02 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Jul 19 19:18:04 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Transition to MASTER STATE
Jul 19 19:18:05 001 Keepalived_vrrp[9751]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Entering MASTER STATE
```

Log on **loadbalancer_2**:

```
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Jul 19 19:18:08 022 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: Configuration is using : 71869 Bytes
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_healthcheckers[467]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_healthcheckers[467]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_healthcheckers[467]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_healthcheckers[467]: Configuration is using : 12587 Bytes
Jul 19 19:18:08 002 Keepalived_healthcheckers[467]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Jul 19 19:18:09 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Transition to MASTER STATE
Jul 19 19:18:10 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Entering MASTER STATE
Jul 19 19:18:11 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Received lower prio advert, forcing new election
```

Configuration of **loadbalancer_1**:

```
global_defs {
    router_id loadbalancer_1
    lvs_id loadbalancer_1
}
vrrp_instance web_loadbalancer_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 10
    priority 110
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        xx.237.193.132/27 dev eth0
    }
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 45f3fgv1
    }
}
vrrp_instance web_loadbalancer_2 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 20
    priority 200
    smtp_alert
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        xx.237.193.134/27 dev eth0
    }
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 45f3fgv2
    }
}
```

Configuration of **loadbalancer_2**:

```
global_defs {
    router_id loadbalancer_2
    lvs_id loadbalancer_2
}
vrrp_instance web_loadbalancer_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 10
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        xx.237.193.132/27 dev eth0
    }
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 45f3fgv1
    }
}
vrrp_instance web_loadbalancer_2 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 20
    priority 210
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        xx.237.193.134/27 dev eth0
    }
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 45f3fgv2
    }
}
```

Comment: When you lb1 stops receiving messages, can you restart lb2 or the keepalived/vrrpd service to generate more logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by me.
Initially there was a primary IP-addresses on **eth0** interfaces (**lb_1** and **lb_2**), and I've used them in **keepalived** configuration.

```
On loadbalancer_1 : xx.237.193.132/27
On loadbalancer_2 : xx.237.193.134/27
```

Then I've just edited a **keepalived** configuration and replaced those IP-addresses by other in the same subnet:

```
For loadbalancer_1 : xx.237.193.150/27
For loadbalancer_2 : xx.237.193.151/27
```

So when the system starts the **eth0** will be initialized with old primary IP-addresses, but **keepalived** will use other virtual IP-addresses from the same subnet.
I don't know why the first solution doesn't work, I haven't found the explanation or requirements anywhere.

Does anyone can explain what was the problem, and why I can't use a primary IP-addresses that were assigned to an interface at OS boot in **keepalived** configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a **preempt_delay 10** to both MASTER sections.

Looking at the last log entry for server2

> Jul 19 19:18:11 002 Keepalived_vrrp[468]: VRRP_Instance(web_loadbalancer_2) Received lower prio advert, forcing new election

It seems as if it just realized that it could take over as VRRP master. Maybe have a look later in the logs if this did not happen.

It is normal for the first server to start, to assume master as there is no other server, then when the second server becomes active a vrrp re-election should pick the server with the highest priority configured.

Comment: I didn't helped. It seems that when the **loadbalancer_1** takes the IP-address of **loadbalancer_2** IP-address, stop receiving messages, because after that I don't see any entries in log files.